# Google Map fails to load on the first time and sometimes on refresh

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

so i added google map to my website. On first page load - it does not load. When refreshing - sometimes it does not load as well.

Code:

html:

```html
    <div id="map">
    </div>   
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDKxMTYIeZepn8E6EULm9eFZCixv960J2s&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

jquery:

```js
function initMap() {};
$(document).ready(function () {
  initMap = function() {
    var myLatLng = {
      lat: 40.1511,
      lng: -2.150609
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatLng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      styles: [
          ....    
      ]
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: '........',
    });
  }
});
```

P.S. google function is in separate "script.js" file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of all your `$(document).ready` nonsense (as long as `script.js` appears after your `<div id="map"></div>` that's all that matters).

The real problem is probably the weird `initMap` declaration (you declare it first, then redeclare it inside `$(document).ready`.

So `script.js` should look like this:

```
 var initMap = function() {
     var myLatLng = {
         lat: 40.1511,
         lng: -2.150609
     };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 16,
         center: myLatLng,
         disableDefaultUI: true,
         styles: [
             ....    
         ]
     });
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng,
         map: map,
         title: '........'
     });
 }
```

All this, and pop open your console when you load to make sure you don't see any error messages.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded harsh, it wasn't a noob question. People who have been writing JavaScript for many many years still cluelessly wrap everything inside `$(document).ready` not because they know why, but because that's just what they've always done and they think it's necessary.

Comment: If people think this is harsh, SO might not be the place for them. I think there is a new place called SoyOverflow they might like to try.